# c++ issue with template class inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm getting an error when compiling a code that can be trivialized as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
    protected:
        T protectedValue;

        template<class TT>
        class insideClass
        {
            public:
                TT insideClassValue;
        };
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    public:
        void print(T t)
        {
            insideClass<T> ic;    // <-- the problem should be here
            ic.insideClassValue = t;
            std::cout << ic.indideClassValue << std::endl;
        };
};

int main()
{
    double v = 2.;
    B<double> b;
    b.print(v);

    return 0;
};
```

The compiler (g++) gives the following error:

```
main.C: In member function ‘void B<T>::printA()’:
main.C:23:4: error: ‘insideClass’ was not declared in this scope
main.C:23:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
main.C:23:19: error: ‘ic’ was not declared in this scope
```

I figured out that if class A is not a template class, the compilation will not give any error.
I do not understand why making class A a template class results in the described error.
Any idea about the reasons and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Without qualification `insideClass` is a non-dependent name which is looked up during phase 1 look-up. Since the definition of the base depending on a template argument isn't known, names from the base class are ignored and the name isn't found. Qualification and possibly adding `typename` in a strategic place should solve the problem (thanks to remyabel for the notation):

```
typename A<T>::template insideClass<T> ic;
```

The `template` keyword is needed to indicate that what's coming is a template and the `typename` is needed to indicate that happens to be a type. Getting the correct spelling of what a dependent name is supposed to be is sometimes not entirely straight forward. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing the problem is [here](http://ideone.com/o5w2x7) and the solution is [here](http://ideone.com/rB44N1).

Comment: `typename A<T>::template insideClass<T> ic;`  should do the trick.

Comment: @remyabel: yes, this looks right: I was typing on a small mobile device and eventually gave up on trying to get this right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
typedef typename A<T>::template insideClass<T> ic; 
public:
    void print(T t)
    {
        ic ic;
        ic.insideClassValue = t;
        std::cout << ic.insideClassValue << std::endl;
    };
```